# Jupyter notebook wrong path

Tags: python, path, jupyter-notebook, sys.path

I need to test a few functions from a code I am building which I import into a jupyter notebook.

issue is, *simTools_path* is different in the functions and the jupyter notebook. More, when I call these functions from my main python script, it works fine.

**MWE**

*simTools_path/objects/classes.py*

```
simTools_path = os.path.abspath(os.getenv('SIMTOOLS_PATH'))
sys.path.append(simTools_path)

def testPath():
    print 'testPath', simTools_path
```

*jupyter notebook*

```
import os,sys
# paths 
simTools_path = os.path.abspath('../')
os.environ["SIMTOOLS_PATH"] = "simTools_path"
os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = "simTools_path"
sys.path.append(simTools_path)

from objects.classes import testPath

print simTools_path
testPath()
```

results:

```
simTools_path= /home/jhumberto/WORK/Projects/code/simulations_2016-07-14/simTools
testPath= /home/jhumberto/WORK/Projects/code/simulations_2016-07-14/simTools/jupyterNotebooks/simTools_path
```

*Notes:*

1) I use this path variable in different functions inside different modules to load file data relatively to the *simTools_path* path.

2) my jupyter notebook is located in */home/jhumberto/WORK/Projects/code/simulations_2016-07-14/simTools/jupyterNotebooks*

Any ideas?

Comment: Was the line `os.environ["SIMTOOLS_PATH"] = "simTools_path"` supposed to read `os.environ["SIMTOOLS_PATH"] = simTools_path` (no quote marks)? One points to the parent directory, the other to a folder called simTools_path within the current directory.

Comment: @mdurant silly me, that was it! Thanks! can you please write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused the variable `simTools_path` and the literal string `"simTools_path"`. To correct the problem, simply change the line as follows:

```
os.environ["SIMTOOLS_PATH"] = simTools_path
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it :)